# wp_mail() is not working on server

Tags: plugins, email, wp-mail

I am breaking my head from last 1 hour but not getting any idea that what's going wrong with my code...

I am developing my own plugin and I am using `wp_mail()` function for sending mail in that but it's not sending mail it seems.

I tried to use PHP Mailer which is working fine but I want to use `wp_mail()`.. this is my code..

```
  $from = "abc@gmail.com";
    $headers[] = "From:" . $from;
    $send = wp_mail("myemail@gmail.com", "hiii", "hiiii",$headers);
      if($send) {
          echo "send";
        return false;
       } else {
           echo $send;
        return true;
       }
```

Can any body help me to figure out my mistake... I am testing it on my server only...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that you use `$headers` and `$header` spellt differently? I do not understand what you wnat to achieve with your conditional. It returns false if the email is sent?

Comment: $headers and $header is printing mistake here.. sorry for that.. and regarding true and false pls ignore it here...

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP Mailer is working fine do you have the same credentials setup for wp_mail? If you're using an authenticated SMTP for PHP Mailer then you'll possibly need a plugin to get the authentication into wp_mail. There are a few different ones that all work but one is https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `$headers` as a string, and giving a name to the email.

```
$headers = 'From: Your Name <abc@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Do not forget to add the `\r\n` like in the code above if you are using the string version.

If this does not work, try using `wp_mail` without additional headers, and check if it works. Should be sorted then :)